# How to find same string with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some difficult with this one.

I searched about this, and found some examples, but i can't make my own work...

Here goes, JS:

```
 $('#diahora').click(function(event){ 
    var diaSelecao = $('input[name="dia"]:checked').each(function(){});
    var horaSelecao = $('input[name="hora"]:checked').each(function(){});
    var novaHora = horaSelecao.val();
    var novoDia = diaSelecao.val();
    var novoOutros = $('#outrosSelecao').val();
    var novoTotal = $('<a>',{class:""}).text(novoDia + ' ' + novaHora + '; ');
    var outroTotal = $('<a>', {class:""}).text(novoDia + ' ' + novoOutros + '; ');

    if(horaSelecao.val()== 'outros'){
        $('.diasehoras').append(outroTotal);
    }else if($('.diasehoras a').text().indexOf(novoTotal.text()) === true){
        return alert('Dia e hora já selecionados.');
    }else{
        $('.diasehoras').append(novoTotal);
    }

});
```

What it basically do is, from two select fields, it sends the selects to another col, with the selected day and hour.

Now, it need to check with the selected day and hour are already in the  "selected area" and don't repeat it.

I tried the way it's now.

But this is not working.. What should i do instead?

Thanks.

Comment: Why `.each(function(){});`?!? Or `{class:""}`?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Going to use it later.

Comment: Might want to read [mcve]... It's best if you just leave out extraneous code that doesn't have to do with your question.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes should add your answer so this post can be marked as the asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `.indexOf()`, will return the index of the first occurrence of the specified value; -1 if not found.

So for:

```
if(horaSelecao.val()== 'outros'){
    $('.diasehoras').append(outroTotal);
}else if($('.diasehoras a').text().indexOf(novoTotal.text()) === true){
    return alert('Dia e hora já selecionados.');
}else{
    $('.diasehoras').append(novoTotal);
}
```

You will want to update it to:

```
if(horaSelecao.val()== 'outros'){
    $('.diasehoras').append(outroTotal);
}else if($('.diasehoras a').text().indexOf(novoTotal.text()) !== -1){
    return alert('Dia e hora já selecionados.');
}else{
    $('.diasehoras').append(novoTotal);
}
```